# Cannot run program "dx" CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, intellij-idea, ant, dex

I run ant task which use dx command with intellj in windows10.

I add the dx file path to windows PATH environment variable, 
the path I added was "C:\Users\jody\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1"
and I run the ant task.

but I got the error "Cannot run program "dx"  CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified "

Now, my question is how I can fix it?

is it possible jdk version make this problem?

Comment: After changing the PATH, did you open a new command prompt window to run Ant in?

Comment: can you run dx from command line from the same directory of your ant script just by invoking 'dx'?

Comment: I run Ant task from command prompt and I got same error.

Comment: I can run dx from command prompt when I am in same directory of my ant script.

Comment: In other words command line can run dx but when I invoke it from ant script it can not run dx.